# Using Princomp() in R

Tags: r, pca

After running Principal Component Analysis in R using `princomp()` and running `summary()` on the results I got a list of components, their proportion of variance, and their cumulative proportion.  Is there a way to see which variables are actually included in each of these components?

Comment: Maybe this one will help: princomp(cor(data))$loadings

Answer (score 2):

If you use `princomp()`, then it has a `loadings()` method to extract the rotation matrix, or you can access the `$loadings` slot directly.

If you use `prcomp()` instead, then the rotation matrix is also shown in the print output (or can be accessed explicitly via `$rotation`).

For example using the four numeric columns from the `iris` data with `princomp()`:

```
R> pca1 <- princomp(iris[, 1:4], cor = TRUE)
R> pca1
Call:
princomp(x = iris[, 1:4], cor = TRUE)

Standard deviations:
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4 
1.7083611 0.9560494 0.3830886 0.1439265 

 4  variables and  150 observations.
R> loadings(pca1)

Loadings:
             Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
Sepal.Length  0.521  0.377  0.720  0.261
Sepal.Width  -0.269  0.923 -0.244 -0.124
Petal.Length  0.580        -0.142 -0.801
Petal.Width   0.565        -0.634  0.524

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00
```

Or equivalently via `prcomp()`:

```
R> pca2 <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4], scale = TRUE)
R> pca2
Standard deviations:
[1] 1.7083611 0.9560494 0.3830886 0.1439265

Rotation:
                    PC1         PC2        PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length  0.5210659 -0.37741762  0.7195664  0.2612863
Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 -0.92329566 -0.2443818 -0.1235096
Petal.Length  0.5804131 -0.02449161 -0.1421264 -0.8014492
Petal.Width   0.5648565 -0.06694199 -0.6342727  0.5235971
```

The rotation matrix at the end can also be extracted by `pca2$rotation`. This is equivalent to the one from `pca1` except for switching signs on PC2.

Applying `summary(pca1)`, `plot(pca1)`, and `biplot(pca1)` yields equivalent results for both `pca1` and `pca2`.